# QGIS: General tab not showing up under Properties for ESRI shapefiles

Tags: qgis

I'm a QGIS novice, have been using ArcGIS for years. Pulled ESRI shapefiles into a QGIS (version 3.12.1), wanted to select a subset of features (essentially doing what a Definition Query would do in ArcMap). Online help says: Open Properties and select General tab (hammer and screwdriver icon), choose Feature Subset to set up query. Only problem is when I go to Properties, there is no general tab for any of my layers (all ESRI shapefiles). I can see lots of other tabs (symbology, source, etc). Why is that? Is there another way to set up Feature subsets?

Comment: If you question is really about filtering layer you might consider changing your title

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be trying to follow instruction for an older QGIS version, now the 'provider feature filter' is in the 'source' tab of the layer properties (right click then Properties...), you have to click on the 'query builder' button at the bottom to enter your query

Alternatively if you right click on a layer you have a  'Filter...' entry that directly open the query builder, that save you some click.

Both way work exactly the same (the second being a shortcut to the first) and are equivalent to arcmap definition query